# How to restrict specific profiles to create note

Tags: trigger, contentdocument, contentversion, notes, contentnote

I need to restrict users with a specific profile to create **Note** in Salesforce for under lead object. I know that Note object will inherit access level from parent Lead.

I need lead to be accessible and only restrict to create a Note.

To achieve this, Since Note has no validation rules and i opt for trigger on Note object and cant able to success with it.

And there is an object " Content Note "  but we cannot create triggers on it. I tried all available ways and also tried with **content version** and **content document link** but in these triggers cant able to differentiate it is Content Doc link is inserting due to a file upload or note creation

Comment: Could you share what you have tried so far? `i opt for trigger on Note object and cant able to success with it.` also elaborate this statement, what doesn't work?

Comment: @RahulSharma This was not worked for me in my case,  And this is what i want to achive https://gist.github.com/anildevarapu/f86c9c0438ec5318bcdb7b4c8749a7c1